# Wingpanel alarm or timer indicator

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

I am unable to find an alarm or timer indicator for Wingpanel.

Hourglass and Tomato work well, but neither integrate with Wingpanel.

Is this currently available?

Comment: Take a look at Go for it.

Answer (score 3):

You should search for `indicator-remindor`
Here is the ppa and how to install: [indicator-remindor](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/schedule-alarms-reminders-in-ubuntu.html)

After installing remember to log out and back in, or you can use this command:`sudo killall wingpanel`

Then search for remindor or indicator-remindor in applications menu or synapse to start.

It works as an alarm/reminder for ubuntu and ubuntu derivatives including elementary.